# BLE scan Record- Not getting all the advertisement data (service data)

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

We are developing an app in react-native in which we need to scan and read all the manufacturer data and service data as well from the BLE device.

The issue is that we are getting a few details in service data (only 9 bytes) and we supposed to get 31 bytes of data.

**Plugin Used** - https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx

**BLE Device details-**   It is a custom-made hardware that is using nRF52832 SoC

Below is the sample code that we are using:

```
import { BleManager } from 'react-native-ble-plx';
this.manager = new BleManager();

//Checking Bluetooth state
const subscription = this.manager.onStateChange((state) => {
            if (state === 'PoweredOn') {
                this.startDeviceScan(scanTimeout);
                subscription.remove();
            }
    }, true);

//Start Scan
startDeviceScan(scanTimeout) {
        var me = this;
        this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
            if (error) {
                // Handle error (scanning will be stopped automatically)
                console.log("scanningError" + error.message);
                me.startDeviceScan();
                return;
            }
            if (device)
                            // Here we are supposed to get the advertisment data(Manufacturer data) in device object
                this.emit('startScanSuccess', device);
        });
    }
```

**Results we are getting in device object is as follows**
serviceData - Object  =  {00006612-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb:"/QosfgB5h/hZ↵"}
manufacturerData =  "P/8AAQ=="

**Required result** - According to our device specification it should be 
Service data - We should get at least 31 Bytes of data.

With the below plugin we are getting all the data but it does not work in react-native: https://github.com/randdusing/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in fact getting 31 bytes of data. Lets look at the structure of the advertising data, following from the Bluetooth Core Spec V5.0 and the Core Specfication Supplement V6.

The Core Spec specifies that the advertising data should have the following pattern: N structures, each consisting of a length octet, an AD type octet (e.g. manufacturer data) and the corresponding data (see Vol 3, Part C, chap. 11).

You receive the types "service data" and "manufacturer data". These are two structures, each containing a length field, a type field and the data field. The data field of serviceData has a length of 16 bytes, together with length and type we have a structure of 18 bytes. The data field of manufacturer data has a length of 8 bytes, together with length and type we have a structure of 10 bytes.

So now we have 28 bytes. Furthermore, advertising needs a flags field where it is defined if this is limited or general discovery, if BR/EDR is supported etc. (see Core Supplement, Part A, chap. 1.3).

This flags field has a data field of one octet. Together with length and type we have an additional structure of 3 bytes, so all in all you get an advertisement with 31 bytes. And that is the maximum; any byte exceeding the maximum will be cut off.

What to do now? Put the information into the scan response data. By using an active scan, you can request the scan response data in addition to the advertising data. Remove the manufacturer data from the advertising data and put it in the scan response data. Then it should work.